# What data retrieval method is good if I don't know schema of database?

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework, data-retrieval

I am retrieving all tables, and make sql. But I want something that can handle Take, Skip. Differences between databases.

Comment: What is the problem? Why downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip/take/similar are mapper functions... If you don't know the schema you can't have a model to map to, really. Ultimately, then, I suspect you're looking at more general tools like SQL and DataTable (storing data from an unknown schema is one of the very few uses I have for DataTable). This won't have skip/take, but most databases have a SQL way of doing that (for example, row-number in SQL server).

Comment: You suggest to invent yet another library that collecting sql parts into big sql, cool.